# Want to understand this paper that uses templates

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I found this paper searching for links about C++ template metaprogramming.  I'm new to both security and templates in C++ and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  I'm asking for no other reason that it piqued my interest, and I'd like to learn more in general.

Here is the paper: https://www.cisuc.uc.pt/publication/showfile?fn=1357250736_metaobfv3.pdf

Or just do a search on the name:  Binary code obfuscation through C++ template metaprogramming

I can't seem to figure out how a programmer would use this.  Are they creating types via templates then using those types in the original code itself?  Here is some code used:

```
struct uint32 {
    unsigned int x_;
    uint32(unsigned int x) : x_(x) {}
    uint32(const uint32 &oth) : x_(oth.x_) {}
    uint32 &operator=(const uint32 &oth) { x_ = oth.x_; return *this; }
    operator unsigned int() const { return x_; }
};

static inline uint32 operator+(const uint32 &a, const uint32 &b) {
    return uint32(ObfuscatedAdder<unsigned int>::eval(a.x_, b.x_));
}
```

This is a small portion from page 6.  I'm trying to figure out how a programmer using their techniques would go about creating...lets say an algorithm...then obfuscate it.

This would be the addition obfuscation I assume.  How would I take a statement like:

```
unsigned int foo = 5 + 7;
```

in code and use the template to obfuscate it into a more complex identity?

Comment: It would have to be something like `unsigned int foo = uint32(5) + uint32(7);` since built-in types don't support operator overloading.

Comment: Well, yes. But that's what I'm trying to figure out.  Are they requiring the programmer to create all unsigned integers as type uint32, then overloading each operator using custom obfuscation methods?

Comment: I guess the answer is, yes, all arithmetic that needed to be obfuscated would need to use types such as `uint32`.

Comment: As I understood you just need to do all the math using their data types: `unsigned int foo = uint32(5) + 7;` You can write it a bit nicer using "user defined literals" of C++11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsigned int foo = 5 + 7;` won't be obfuscated as this falls under `constant folding`. and would be replaced simply with `unsigned int foo = 12;` at compile time.

The technique is particularly useful for expressions like.

```
uint32 a = 5;
uint32 b = 7;
unsigned int foo = a + b;
```

Comment: They state they use complicated identities for integer arithmetic that are not easily reduced by constant folding or other compiler optimization methods.  The implementation of these is in the eval function.

Comment: Constant magic numbers are anyways already something obfuscated. For ex `Factorial<5>::value` is a **compile time constant**, yet an analyzer can not understand the logic behind its calculation by reverse engineering the binary. On the other hand if your requirements change, you can replace Factorial<5>::value with Factorial<6>::value + 7, and just recompiling the code. So your code is still manageable. You have hidden some logics from analyzer by moving them to compilation stage instead of runtime(binary).

Comment: In `unsigned int foo = 5 + 7;` there is no binary output, so there is no way we can make it harder to analyze.

Comment: Assume that the example is the one you used in your answer.  Assume that the '+' operator is overloaded to generate a series of boolean operations using templates that is random but will produce identical output to 'a + b'.  This might produce binary output?

Comment: Right, this would produce binary output that is random still producing the same result. Good thing is if you want non obfuscated version of code, all you need to do is to comment the structure and add `typedef unsigned int uint32;` in place of structure. No method is fool-proof, but it will make binary harder to digest for the analyzers.